# How to define a max limit of selected items in TwinColSelect

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to define a maximum number of selected items in TwinColSelect in my vaadin ui. How can I achieve it. I want to allow the user to select only 4 planets out of available 8.My current code is

```
TwinColSelect table = new TwinColSelect();
table.setImmediate(true);

String planets[] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
for (int pl=0; pl<planets.length; pl++)
    table.addItem(planets[pl]);
table.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        /*String [] arr=(String [] )event.getProperty().getValue();
        if(arr.length>=4){
            return;
        }*/
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement something like this by changing select's value:

```
//Constant declared somewhere in the class
private static final int SELECTED_ITEMS_LIMIT = 4;

...

table.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Collection selectedItems = (Collection) event.getProperty().getValue();
        if(selectedItems.size()>SELECTED_ITEMS_LIMIT) { //Set no more than SELECTED_ITEMS_LIMIT values
            Set<String> noMoreThanLimitItems = new HashSet<String>(selectedItems.size());
            int counter = 0;
            for(Object item : selectedItems) {
                if(counter>=SELECTED_ITEMS_LIMIT) {
                    break;
                }
                noMoreThanLimitItems.add((String) item);
                counter++;
            }
            event.getProperty().setValue(noMoreThanLimitItems);
        }  
    }
});
```

**Drawbacks:**

- Code is server-side. So, more than four planets might appear as selected between browser requests.
- Call to `Property.setValue` fires `ValueChangeEvent`. So, handling code will be executed twice every time when user tries to select more than four planets

Comment: Thanks friend. It works fine. Thanks for the detailed explanation as well

Comment: @StevenBellens Thanks for your edit! I rolled it back for the following reasons. *First,* I want to keep this answer helpful for Vaadin 6. *Second,* I didn't test it properly. I suggest that you post a separate answer for Vaadin 7. I'd be happy to upvote it and to post a link to it. Again, thank you for your valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to default locale in advance. Yesterday i made some eddits to the above code which remove the first drawback mentioned in the other answer, as well as changed the add which became decrepated.

The answer for Vaadin 7 would be as follows then

```
table.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Collection selectedItems = (Collection) event.getProperty().getValue();
    if(selectedItems.size()>SELECTED_ITEMS_LIMIT) { //Set no more than SELECTED_ITEMS_LIMIT values
        Set<String> noMoreThanLimitItems = new HashSet<String>(selectedItems.size());
        int counter = 0;
        for(Object item : selectedItems) {
            if(counter>=SELECTED_ITEMS_LIMIT) {
                break;
                }
            noMoreThanLimitItems.add((String) item);
            counter++;
        }
        event.getProperty().setValue(noMoreThanLimitItems);
        //cast to twincol to get the needed functions
        //markasdirty makes the object be repainted, so you wil not see more then 4 selected
        ((TwinColSelect)event.getProperty()).markasdirty();
    }  
}
});
```